# Need to allocate Qty based on the Set Logic

Tags: google-sheets

I have google sheet, in that table 2 I got the values for Each POs. I need to allocate those total Qty GRN wise. (Result need to show in the "GRN Wise Allocated Qty" column)

Please refer the below Snap shot and G-Sheet for more detail

[image: Snap Shot]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lIRLGBk9PIE9xRlW0MRA7kcGZaECbR1gyLwhryxUfX4/edit?usp=sharing

Best regard

Indika

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```
=N(VLOOKUP(A4,E$4:F$7,2,)<>SUMIF(A$3:A3,A4,C$3:C3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try `COUNTIFS()` and `XLOOKUP()`.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$4:$A4,A4)<=XLOOKUP(A4,$E$4:$E$7,$F$4:$F$7),1,0)
```

To use the formula as dynamic spill array, try-

```
=MAP(A4:A15,
LAMBDA(x,
IF(COUNTIFS(A4:INDEX(A:A,ROW(x)),x)<=XLOOKUP(x,E4:E7,F4:F7),1,0)
))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Harun24hr, 
Thanks a lot, Your answer working well for me , Thanks lot

Best regard
Indika